# How does the database write log atomically?

Tags: mysql, database, transaction-log, system-design

In section 9.3.2 of ["Principles of Computer System Design"](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-004-principles-of-computer-system-design-an-introduction-spring-2009/online-textbook/atomicity_open_5_0.pdf) `LOG` is a procedure to write a log atomically (with all-or-nothing semantic) to disk to implement [write-ahead-log protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging). But the book does not discuss the details about implementation of `LOG`. I want to know in practice how the `LOG` procedure is implemented, such as Mysql, Oracle, etc.

Comment: Terminate the log entry with a marker that indicates the entry is complete?

Comment: @eggyal How can you make sure the marker is in the valid state? It also must be written atomically, so beg the question.

Comment: Read it back to see if the marker is present?  If it is, all is well; if it's not, the log entry is invalid and can be ignored/discarded.